# Jenkins startup thread died unexpectedly due to an uncaught exception message

Tags: jenkins

During Jenkins startup I see below exception. How to resolve this exception message.

```
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
--> setting agent port for jnlp
Feb 07, 2018 3:23:43 PM hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler$DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtException
SEVERE: A thread (Thread-9/51) died unexpectedly due to an uncaught exception, this may leave your Jenkins in a bad way and is usually indicative of a bug in the code.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at tcp-slave-agent-port$_run_closure1.doCall(tcp-slave-agent-port.groovy:9)
        at tcp-slave-agent-port$_run_closure1.doCall(tcp-slave-agent-port.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:495)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**to resolve this error updated code like this.**

```
import hudson.model.*;
import jenkins.model.*;


Thread.start {
      sleep 10000
      println "--> setting agent port for jnlp"
      def env = System.getenv()
      if(env['JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT'] ){
        int port = env['JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT'].toInteger()
        Jenkins.instance.setSlaveAgentPort(port)
        println "--> setting agent port for jnlp... done"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from init.groovy.d/tcp-slave-agent-port.groovy which is created by docker-jenkins https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/init.groovy:

```
import hudson.model.*;
import jenkins.model.*;


Thread.start {
      sleep 10000
      println "--> setting agent port for jnlp"
      def env = System.getenv()
      int port = env['JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT'].toInteger()
      Jenkins.instance.setSlaveAgentPort(port)
      println "--> setting agent port for jnlp... done"
}
```

It happens when the environment variable JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT is not set.

Comment: updated code like this `import hudson.model.*;
import jenkins.model.*;


Thread.start {
      sleep 10000
      println "--> setting agent port for jnlp"
      def env = System.getenv()
      if(env['JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT'] ){
        int port = env['JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT'].toInteger()
        Jenkins.instance.setSlaveAgentPort(port)
        println "--> setting agent port for jnlp... done"
      }
}`

Comment: I added the environment variable JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT to 50000 and the error stopped appearing but not sure if its the correct slave agent port number.